# Exporting a value from a function or default in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have the following the code like this.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native'

export default {
    baseURL: 'http://mywebsite.com/JsonApi/',
};
```

In the code, I am using the base url for api calls. Now, sometimes, I want to add a sub domain to the domain. And, the sub domain values are taking from AsyncStorage. How can I modify the code to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can get value from Async storage and set that into state.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      subdomain: '',
    };
  }

retrieveData = async () => {
  try {
     const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('your subdomain stored key');
     this.setState({ subdomain: value });
     const baseURL = `http://${this.state.subdomain}.mywebsite.com/JsonApi/`;
   } catch (error) {
     console.log(error);
   }
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.retrieveData();
}

render() {
    return (
      <View/>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How can I take the sub domain key value from the returning view ..? Can I return multiple items like this ..? Can we retrieve state data from  view ?

Comment: I am unable to understand your question?

Comment: I am now exporting the baseURL as like the code above. First issue I face was, I don't know how to take values from async storage and append it. Using the class (your code above), it is solved. As per your code, you are returning a view, right ..? How to take that base URL from another component ..?

Comment: you need to send that state as props to your other component.

Comment: No. I haven't tried. What I am trying to achieve, to remove this render part and directly export like a const. Is that possible ?

Comment: I think no, you can't do like that, you need to use state and pass the value as props to get that value into another component.

Comment: But, I think it's possible. Thats what I am looking for.

Comment: Looks like it's not possible. Now, i am trying the way you said. There is a problem. How to get this props in the constructor ? I am taking values from another component.It should be more like a function call.

Comment: You can access data via this.props. // your value

Comment: No you can access the props inside super function, and set that props value into state.